# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'instancemethod' objects

Tags: python

I am very new to Python. I have a script which does a ssh to the unix host but I am getting the below error while running the python script.

Code command

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -q "+host+" "+command
```

Error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'instancemethod' objects
```

Comment: Can you show us the command script ?

Comment: How does the script look like

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
host = '1.2.3.4'
command = 'ls'
ssh_string = "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -q "+host+" "+command
print(ssh_string)
#ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -q 1.2.3.4 ls
```